# I've worked as a waitress. Should I indicate this in my PhD application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I've worked as a waitress. Should I indicate this in my PhD application? How will that affect my application?

Comment: This could be relevant in certain fields, such as sociology or psychology or food science, but for most academic areas I don't see how this is any more relevant than any of the other part time or full time jobs you've had up to now. Among other things I did before my last application to graduate school included a line cook at a fish/steak restaurant, several separate jobs "flipping hamburgers" at fast food restaurants, keypunch operator (i.e. data entry), farm work in summers, assistant to a bricklayer (i.e. carry bricks), and others. I didn't think any of these were worth mentioning.

Comment: Positive point anyway. But do not expect anything from it. Consider country tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sort of employment is unnecessary to include and will be of no benefit if you do. I suggest only doing so if you need to account for a long gap. Even then, you should say why that was necessary to do. And, if you are in mathematics, as the "handle" implies, write about anything you did that was productive in that field.

It might even be better to describe it as "short term, non-academic employment" without describing its nature.

Most people will find this sort of employment irrelevant, and those that don't would be more likely to consider it a negative. You want your application to be positive-focused on how and why you expect to be a success in doctoral studies and thereafter.

Comment: Why would someone consider that as a negative?

Comment: @user111388, people have all sorts of prejudices, including against low paid workers. It doesn't have to be rational to affect you.

Comment: Oh wow. I thought all/most students (have to) do lowpaid jobs to finance their studies..